# Конструкция типа "по имяреку", подразумевающая косвенную цитату

Tags: значения

Как правило, если в литературе встречается цитата, то при упоминании автора употребляется его имя. А что означают подписи, оформленные по образцу "По гражданину N."? Может ли быть, например, что высказывание это было произнесено не от лица самого автора, а от героя одного из его произведений?

Пример:

> Тот, кто не имеет представления о совершенстве, довольствуется тем, что есть, не спорит с действительностью, которая становится для него тождественной со справедливостью, с благом, с красотою. Для такого человека нет движения, нет жизни. (По Амиелю)

Comment: Вообще, это обычно означает не дословную точность цитаты. Когда смысл сохранён, а формулировка немного изменена. Для пущей точности ответа было бы хорошо увидеть пример в вопросе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Упомянутая вами конструкция часто встречается в значении "в представлении N, в системе выстроенных им ценностей".

Например:

> Но Монтальво также намекает на то, что «ад — это другие», в точности
>   по Сартру.

или

> Экзистенция, по Кьеркегору, является главным предметом мысли, потому
>   что этот вопрос наиболее важен для человека — того, кто существует.

Возвращаясь к вашему вопросу, чаще всего речь идёт о некоей трактовке представлений автора, выводы о которых сделаны на основе их публицистических (и шире - историософских) работ.

Вместе с тем, если у данного конкретного художника авторская линия чётко представлена - ну или  подразумевается, что чётко представлена))) в художественном произведении, то это тоже "считается". Например, часто говорят "по Достоевскому" или "по Толстому" имея ввиду цитаты именно из художественных произведений.