# I (have a meeting,run,blank) from X to Y in the morning. с/к or от/до?

Tags: предлоги

In this question:

[От/До and С/В(На) disambiguation](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/%D0%9E%D1%82-%D0%94%D0%BE-and-%D0%A1-%D0%92%D0%9D%D0%B0-disambiguation)

there is answers to most of my questions. However, the use of к is left out..

I've seen things like, "(I have a meeting/I talk) from six until eight in the morning." -> "(У меня встреча/Я говорю) с/от шести к/до восеми утра." with genitive forms of the numbers, and с and к together, or от and до together.

So what about using к?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`от... к...` is simply not used in denotation of duration, only as indication of direction

> он шёл от победы к победе

`с... к...` i can't think of a situation where they'd appear in combination

in the context of time `к` means `close to`, `around`, `about`, `by`

> я буду к восьми - i'll come at about 8 (by 8 i will have come)

Comment: Just to add one more degree of complexity, because it is a common English construction.. What about, "I talk from six until around eight in the morning." Is it:     "Я говорю с шести до к восеми утра."

Comment: For Russian it's a difficult sentence to render exactly, it will look like `я выступаю с шести до примерно/примерно до восьми утра`, so you use adverbs meaning `approximately` - `примерно/приблизительно`, because this is essentially the function of 'about' in the English sentence. Russian doesn't combine prepositions.

Comment: "K" is used as "to" but not as "until": заходите часам **к** двум.

Comment: @nate : "я говорю **с** шести **до** восьми"